# jQuery click action not working for all iterating items

Tags: jquery

For a pet project, I have made a way for users to comment on uploaded pictures. Now using jQuery, on click of view comments I show and hide the comments. The functionality however works only for the first picture in the list, and not for the rest of them.

I read about using each function and then calling the click for every element using `this`. However, that is not working either. Can someone please correct me ?

HTML:

```
     <div id="show">
         <h6>View Comments</h6>
        </div>
        <div id="menu" style="display:none;">
          {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
            <p style="margin:0;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#show').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $('#menu').each(function(){
    $(this).toggle("slide");
  });
});
});
```

Comment: `$('#menu').each(function(){` <= ids cannot be repeated.  This line doesn't make sense.

Comment: any suggestions on how to tackle this ?

Comment: you can use a class or put all comments in a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend turning show into a class and embedding the hidden comments within the same div so you can easily select it with jquery.  For example..

```
<div class="show">
         <h6>View Comments</h6>
  <div class="menu" style="display:none;">
          {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
            <p style="margin:0;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

And your JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.show', function() {     
    $(this).find('.menu').toggle("slide"); //Look for child menu option
});
});
```

As you see in the comments above, it's important to never have elements on the page with same ID.  It will cause issues like you were experiencing.

find is useful because it only searches down in the parent container. So in this example it is looking for elements in the "show" div with the class name "menu".